# "text-decoration: blink" & IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why text-decoration: blink wont work in IE ?
**What is the work around ?**
Is there a non JS work around?
Do Microsoft  have a plan to support this style?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for <blink>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE doesn't support it. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element

Also, don't. There's a reason it isn't implemented, and finding a workaround will do nothing but annoy your users.

Comment: What is the reason ?"There's a reason it isn't implemented"

Comment: It's annoying and distracting.

Read the "Usability and accessibility" section in the Wikipedia link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether Microsoft is planning to put that in but for the moment you are out of luck as far as IE (obviously) is concerned. [No support for it.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/199806.html)