# <blink> tag in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Neither the `<blink>` tag nor the `text-decoration:blink;` style in css are supported in Internet Explorer.

Is there any technique available for making blinking text in IE?

Comment: Blinking text is usually a bad idea. What justifies its use in your situation?

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-42025.html

Comment: noooooooo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! everytime when someone uses <blink> tag, a kitten dies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text blinking jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery)

Comment: Also relevant: [“text-decoration: blink” & IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170692/text-decoration-blink-ie)

Comment: Even I don't know what a `<blink>` tag is. /sarcasm

Comment: Everyone here is correct to say that you should never use `<blink>`.  But what they didn't tell you is that [`<marquee>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) is preferred. >:)

Comment: @rochal: only when it's epileptic

Comment: @reinierpost, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlCoBra6PfU :)

Comment: I thought you could only use <blink> within <marquee> tags??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for <blink>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink/23951515#23951515

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Avoid blinking, if possible - it annoys people.

But you can do it with JS/jQuery like this:

```
setInterval(jQuery('.blinking').toggle, 1500 );
```

That'll show/hide anything with the blinking class every 1.5 seconds.

So in the HTML you would do:

```
<span class="blinking">hello!</span>
```

But again, think very carefully about whether it should be blinking!

If you need something to specifically draw a user's attention (and for whatever reason regular emphasis/highlighting/etc isn't good enough), then instead of on-off blinking (where the text dissappears for half the time), consider changing the colour, or a blinking underline/border, or similar.

The key thing is, if something is important enough to visually annoy the user then it should remain readable.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("$('.blink').fadeOut().fadeIn();",1500);
});
```

and a class link this

```
<div class="blink">BLING BLING...</div>
```

see working demo http://jsfiddle.net/SGrmM/

You can also use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("$('.blink').fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150);",1000);
});
```

see working demo http://jsfiddle.net/SGrmM/1/

see booth examples in the same fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SGrmM/2/