# <blink > tag not afftect on IE all version

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<blink> tag in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928103/blink-tag-in-internet-explorer)

Hai

I have used blink tag to blink a word. It's displays in mozilla. But IE it's not blinking. 
How I do this?
 I have used

```
<blink>* New </blink>
```

Does any one know this?

Comment: You *have* to use blink tags?

Comment: See [<blink> tag in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928103/blink-tag-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: You've discovered a bug! I'm sure Microsoft will get right on it, so it should be OK tomorrow.

Comment: This is a rare cases where IE is superior.

Comment: *(reference)* http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/blink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blink tag is not a standards-compliant HTML tag. If you absolutely need to blink text, then either use CSS or JS:

```
.blink {
    text-decoration: blink;
}
```

Here is a jQuery plugin that lets you blink text and should work in IE:

http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/2826

Answer (score 4):

`<blink>` is non-[standard](http://w3.org/TR/HTML4/) and has never been supported by Microsoft browsers. Blinking is so awful that, while [CSS provides a method](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) due to demand for it, it explicitly makes support for the property optional (so a browser can be fully CSS 2.1 compliant without supporting the feature). Internet Explorer does not support this method either.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try closing the blink tag like this:

```
</blink>
```